# Non-reproducible SQL access control error in Snowflake

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks

I'm facing a non-reproducible SQL error with Snowflake. I run a scheduled job on Databricks which writes to a snowflake table. Sometimes I get *SQL access control error* which is very strange given that I've required access level and the job succeeds sometimes. There isn't much literature on this issue apart from the error definition on SQLAlechemy. Below I've pasted the error with sensitive details obscured. I haven't been able to find the root cause of this error.

```
-> df_temp.to_sql("table_name", con3, if_exists='append', index=False, index_label=None)

ProgrammingError: (snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 003001 (42501): SQL access control error:
Insufficient privileges to operate on table 'TABLE_NAME'
[SQL: INSERT INTO table_name (index, YYYYYXXXXX]
[parameters: XXXX]
(Background on this error at: `https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405`)
```

Comment: Does the user running the sql have multiple assigned roles? Thus depanding on the order of things may had a role swap on a prior task/step?

Comment: Or are those objects recreated. Thus could be influx between replacement and permission reassignments?

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim the user does have multiple roles but there's just one task i.e. dp_temp.to_sql(). Can you please elaborate on your 2nd comment?

Comment: if you are using a "automation" user, and they do stuff like user creation (which requires role_a) and simple data loading which uses role_b, and you are using thread pooling, thus you could run a string of commands, at the same time, and while at the start of the admin sequence you "set role_a","comand_b","command_c" before comand_c is run another "use role_b","copy data" command runs, and then command_c runs on a session with a different role. That is the gist of what I am asking "is this happening"

Comment: where-as if the user had only a single role, there there would be zero chance of this type of problem happening. and I would lean more to some form of, are your roles or object getting recreated.

Comment: Both are simply multi-threading concurrency issues (which this really sounds like), it just depends which end is the "unexpected" change happen at this "inconceivable" same time.